Android Navigation Drawer - Left Position of Item
i have the following problem with positioning a item in the navigation drawer of my android app.
I want to position the second Testx (nav_Test) at the left position where the first Testx (the menu header) is. or at least where "Test A" is.
Right now there is space for the icon reserved left to the "Testx" of nav_test.
Is there a solution for this?
This is my xml activity_main_drawer.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">
    
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:title="Testx"
            android:visible="true"
            android:id="@+id/nav_grp_testx">
            <menu>
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_testa"
                    android:title="Test A" />
            </menu>
        </item>
    </group>
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:title="Testx"
            android:id="@+id/nav_test"/>
    </group>
</menu>



Use a style to control the padding and icon space globally
<style name="NavigationDrawerItemStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Base.TextView">     <item name="android:iconSpaceReserved">false</item>     <item name="android:paddingStart">16dp</item> </style>
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView     android:id="@+id/nav_view"     android:layout_width="wrap_content"     android:layout_height="match_parent"     app:itemTextAppearance="@style/NavigationDrawerItemStyle"     app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

Do you have a recipe how to use a style?
I don't know where to put this.
